# Why does calling gem.bat from a cmd file exit after the first call?

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd, rubygems

I'm calling `gem` commands in a Windows `.cmd` file, but it exits after the first command. What gives?

```
gem sources --add http://gems.github.com 
gem install haml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by calling the first `gem` command through `cmd.exe`, but I'm still keen to hear explanations of what is going on.

```
cmd.exe /c gem sources --add http://gems.github.com   
gem install haml
```

Comment: I'm glad you could be of service to you... ;)

Answer (score 5):

The `gem` command is actually a batch file in your `PATH`. For example, `C:\Ruby192\bin\gem.bat`. Calling a batch file like this from a batch/cmd file automatically exits the entire session at the end of the *called* batch file. There is a special command that returns to the *calling* batch/cmd file. Use the [`CALL`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command before every call to another batch file.

```
CALL gem sources --add http://gems.github.com
CALL gem install haml
```